# Not possible to choose program x as default program

Tags: windows-7

I have a PHP file and need it to open with Notepad++. However, if I right click and select `open with...` and choose Notepad++ then it still opens with editor.exe and Notepad++ does not even appear in the list (see screenshot, window at right).

[image]

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Browse button and navigate to  Notepad ++ in Program Files or Program Files x86. Check this box "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file".

[image]

2. You can try this free software [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/#)

Comment: Thats exactly what I am doing, and it does not work. It still opens with Editor.exe

Comment: Go to Notepad ++, Settings/Prefrencess/File Association and choose web script -> .php

Comment: Does not work either, It still opens with Editor.exe